# "Get" Button On App Store Is Blurred Out For Almost EVERY App

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I have been having an issue lately with my app store app. When I go to buy an app, I've found that nearly every app I try to buy has one thing in common--the "get" button is blurred/greyed out. When I try to press on the "get" button when it is like this, it has no reaction, therefore, I cannot buy the app that I want. It is absolutely FRUSTRATING and I want to know how to fix it. Who knows--one day, I may need an extremely important app for a serious reason and I won't be able to buy it. And I don't want that. Is the reason for this perhaps because my father has enable restriction on my IPad? Is the way to fix it for him to put in the restricions code? But whatever the reason or way to fix it is, I want answers, and I hope you can give them to me.

Comment: When you say "nearly every app I try to buy" do you mean every app or **almost** every app?  Have you asked your father if he put restrictions on your downloads?  Have you tried to log out of the App Store and log back in?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the download apps restriction has been enabled. Ask whoever enabled this to disable this restriction either temporarily or permanently. I would also check that you are signed into the correct region in App store settings and that your account is verified and has no outstanding payment issues.

To check go to;
Settings > General > Restrictions

Hope this helps.